# How do I add a reaction to a specific message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I would like the bot to react to a message that i have defined (in this case, the ID message "708780848853286962") but when i try to do that an error happens on the console, how do i proceed?

How am i doing:

```
let msg = '708780848853286962'
msg.react('')
```

Console error:

```
TypeError: msg.react is not a function
```

Comment: which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Discord version: 12.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch that message first, as far as discord.js is concerned with your current code, you're just doing `'708780848853286962'.react('')`.

You also need to know what channel the message is in.

```js
const msg = client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID).messages.fetch('708780848853286962')
msg.react('')
```